# Lazy quantifier and /s modifier

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a little problem and don't find any solution :(

I try to replace this text :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%"><a href="http://www.test.com/myfile.pdf?min" target="_blank">Menus 18 €</a></div></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="http://www.test.com/myfile.pdf?min" target="_blank">Menus 24 et 26 €</a></div></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="http://www.test.com/myfile.pdf?min" target="_blank">Menus 30 et 37 € </a></div></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="http://www.test.com/myfile.pdf?min">La Carte détaillée&nbsp;<br>
            (Entrées - Viandes - Poissons)</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

with this regex :

```
/<a.*?href=\"(.+.pdf\?min)\".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/s
```

But instead of returning each link replaced by ok, it replaces only one occurrence. I thought the greedy quantifier .*? could do the trick but not...

To try it : https://regex101.com/r/iF7dV0/1

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: As you're new to StackOverflow, let me share this [classic post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/989121) with you. TLDNR: do not use regexes for html work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn the inbetween `.+` to `.+?`, so that it would do a non-greedy match or otherwise it would greedily match many characters as much as possible.

```
<a.*?href=\"(.+?.pdf\?min)\".*?>(.*?)<\/a>
               ^
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iF7dV0/2)

Answer (score 0):

use the global g modifier, to get every occurence

Comment: No, the problem is greediness.  His regex consumes everything from the first `<a href` tag to the last `</a>` on the first attempt.  Also, if he's using PHP, there *is* no `g` flag.  `preg_replace()` automatically does a global replace unless you tell it not to.

Comment: sorry, there was/is little hint he was using php